# Using Java method to display HTML code

Tags: java

Hey folks, ok so this is my problem, I need to display HTML code in a jsp, which wouldn't be a problem, except a requirement for this project is that we place all the code in a public class file and have seperate methods for each chunk(header, sidebar footer, etc).  Now here's where i'm confused:

"Your method should take the PrintWriter as a parameter to print out each line of HTML, and should have a return type of void"

What does that mean?  How do I pass the PrintWriter into a method?
Does this make sense to anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is far from clear, but it sounds like you need to write code like this:

```
public void writeHeader(PrintWriter out)
{
    ...
}

public void writeSidebar(PrintWriter out)
{
    ...
}

public void writeFooter(PrintWriter out)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It means that your method (that you will have to name yourself) will have one argument of type PrintWriter. In your method you should then call that variable's print method.

I am deliberately vague here, because you should do some of your homework yourself :)

Comment: Oh no! Jon Skeet answered the same question as me! I am doomed :)

Comment: But he used C# style braces so I'm upvoting yours :P

Comment: Me too :( I'm doomed as well!

Answer (score 1):

> *"Your method should take the PrintWriter as a parameter to print out each line of HTML, and should have a return type of void"*

That's pretty clear to me:

```
/* return type void -->*/ void yourMethodNameHere( PrintWriter parameter ) { /*<--  Pw as parameter*/
                          }
```

> *What does that mean?*

Exactly that

> *How do I pass the PrintWriter into a method?*

Ah, this is the interesting part. I'll give you a hint, check it **out**: http://www.google.com/search?&q=jsp+predefined+variables

> *Does this make sense to anyone?*

Pretty much